# Font mismatch with Linux Libertine and siunitx package

Tags: fonts, math-mode, siunitx, libertine

Following example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}

\begin{document}
  \chapter{Test}
  Anhand einer Kalibrationsgerade des Photolinkers in DMSO konnte der Extintionskoeffizient des Photolinkers $\epsilon_{PL}$ im 
  Konzentrationsbereich $c_{PL-02}$: \SI{0.02}{\micro\mole\per\liter} - 
  \SI{0.1}{\micro\mole\per\liter} bestimmt werden. Mittels des  Extintionskoeffizienten 
  $\epsilon_{PL}=15766$ des Phototolinker und dem Lambert-Beer Gesetz wurde die 
  folgende Gleichung zur Bestimmung des DS, hergeleitet.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now the number in the math environment (which looks really big) does not match the one in the siunitx environment. Why is this and is there a better way to have a font match between this two? I should mention I use `lualatex`.

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks! I should mention that I get also a lot of `checksum mismatch in font <bla>.vf ignored` messages. Is now the package newtxmath in charge for the math mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `siunitx`: it's the font used for numbers in math mode that's wrong.

You can solve the issue with this block of font settings:

```
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

%%% Uncomment the following line, if something is still wrong    
% \DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{LinuxLibertineO-LF}{m}{n}
```

The commented line might be needed, depending on the installed version of `newtxmath.sty`, which has undergone several changes in the last months.

The messages about checksum mismatches with LuaLaTeX are innocuous, albeit annoying.

Comment: Shouldn't `newtx` take care of this? As I understand, the main idea behind this package is to create a math appearance that perfectly fits the main text. And the figures (numbers) are a main part of this, of course. So, why are the numbers not set in Libertine although we use `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}`?

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke The `no-math` option to `fontspec` is making the difference; without it, `fontspec` hijacks the `operators` font.

Comment: Okay, but the (in my naive view) established `\usepackage{libertine}` can not be used to achieve the effect, we need to use `\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}` in order to get Libertine numbers, right? All this appears quite magic to me.

Comment: My last comment is wrong, `\usepackage{libertine}` just needs to be declared after loading `fontspec`, as Herbert points out below.

Answer (score 6):

with current TeXLive there is no problem. However, all font stuff depending to the old LaTeX loading mechanism should be done *before* you load the OpenType fonts:

```
[...]
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution might be to use the `libertinus` package as on the [LaTeX Font Catalog](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/libertinusserif/).

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{siunitx}



\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
 Anhand einer Kalibrationsgerade des Photolinkers in DMSO konnte der Extintionskoeffizient des Photolinkers $\epsilon_{PL}$ im 
 Konzentrationsbereich $c_{PL-02}$: \SI{0.02}{\micro\mole\per\liter} - 
\SI{0.1}{\micro\mole\per\liter} bestimmt werden. Mittels des  Extintionskoeffizienten 
$\epsilon_{PL}=15766$ des Phototolinker und dem Lambert-Beer Gesetz wurde die 
folgende Gleichung zur Bestimmung des DS, hergeleitet.
\end{document}
```

[image: math font matches main font]