# Hat over numbers without math mode in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, accents

I'm using the Alegreya font in XeLaTeX and I'm wondering if I can put a hat over numbers outside of math mode. I ask because Alegreya doesn't have math functionality, so the integers default to CM font, which ends up looking pretty amateur in the context; euler also doesn't help. Is there a way to do this outside of math mode, thus keeping Alegreya's numbers?

Or, of course, is there some other work around to put a hat above Alegreya's numbers?

[Font mismatch with Linux Libertine and siunitx package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97299/font-mismatch-with-linux-libertine-and-siunitx-package/97302#97302) might be helpful but I'm not sure how yet...

MWE:

```
%XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[osf]{Alegreya}
\begin{document}
I want $\hat{1}$ where the 1 is in the Alegreya font. \^{1} seems to only work for l\^{e}tters.
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\^{1}` ?......

Comment: I've tried this, but it results in a lone integer. It's a 1 in the Alegreya font (progress of a kind?), but there's no caret above it.

Comment: Not that I would be able to truly debug it beyond trial and error, but could you make a short and simple [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) containing `\^{1}`? Because if I just make a very simple document and compile it with XeLaTeX, it works: `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} A\^{1}A \end{document}`

Comment: The Alegreya font has no U+0302 COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT

Comment: Since we are in XeLaTeX, I would expect `\^{1}` to call a real `1` with a hat (which might not be available in Alegreya. Is that it? In any case, two fast alternatives (with `mathtools` package for `\text`) `$\hat{\text{1}}$ \^i î`. In any case, it does work in pdfLaTeX, since the font is available, what's the need for XeLaTeX?

Comment: @Sam That's why I ask for a MWE. I've got no idea what Alegreya is and where to get it from.

Comment: Manuel, this is perfect, thanks! @yo, sorry, I assumed it was clear enough that Alegreya was a font, thus no need for a MWE.

Comment: @Sam **Yes, that is clear.** What is not clear is that **how are others supposed to get the font.**

Comment: @Manuel Care to make it an answer? :)

Comment: @yo' It's not really an answer. It's not available in XeLaTeX and the workaround is `\hat{\text{1}}` (the `î` is not really a solution). I think better wait for someones magic to bring a better (or even real) `\^1` in. **EDIT:** like the one that just came in :)

Comment: @Manuel A *hat trick* ;-)

Comment: @yo' Alegreya is included in TeX Live.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Alegreya font seem not to have U+0302 COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT, so only precomposed character with the circumflex over them are available.

However, it has U+02C6 MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT that can be used as substitute.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Alegreya}

\newcommand{\fhat}[1]{\accent"02C6 #1}

\begin{document}
\^a \fhat{1} \fhat{2} \fhat{3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg, this is even better; now I can input something in front of it `$\flat$\fhat{3}` as well, which I couldn't quite do with Manuel's solution.