# Using Linux Libertine fonts for math without newtxmath

Tags: fonts, xetex, amsmath, libertine, mathspec

I'm trying to use Linux Libertine as the math (and main) font, and I used [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88434/4071) to set the math fonts. However, the math output is still CM.

```
\documentclass{minimal}   
\usepackage{amsmath, mathspec, libertine, lipsum}
%\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\setmathsfont[ItalicFont={LinLibertine_RI.otf}]{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setmathrm{LinLibertine_R.otf}
\setboldmathrm{LinLibertine_RB.otf}
\setmathsf{LinBiolinum_RB.otf}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
    \hat{Q}_i=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{G}^2(x) \Sigma^{-1}(x^2) f_i(x)dx
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I try to uncomment the `newtxmath` line, I get an error

> Package mathspec Error: `amsmath' must be loaded earlier than`mathspec'

But I have loaded `amsmath` before `mathspec`!

How do I fix these issues (fixing either is fine, since the goal is to use LL fonts for math).

---

As pointed out, moving `newtxmath` before `amsmath` solves the problem in the above MWE. Now let me change it a bit and include `amsthm` as well, which now leads to a host of other errors such as:

> ! LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined.
>       Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

Comment: @karlkoeller Strange, that seems to work for this example. However, if I add `amsthm` as well, it gives lots of errors...

Comment: The right order is `amsthm`, `newtxmath`, `mathspec`. Don't load `amsmath` since it is loaded by `newtxmath`.

Comment: @karlkoeller Oh dear... never would've though that. If you'd like to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right order to load those packages is `amsthm`, `newtxmath`, `mathspec`

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
```

You don't need to load `amsmath` since it is already loaded by `newtxmath`. That's also the reason why `mathspec` complains when you load `newtxmath` after it.

Moreover, note that both `amsthm` and `newtxmath` define the `\openbox` command. But, while the former defines it through a `\newcommand`, the latter does it through a `\DeclareRobustCommand`, so it does not complain...

Answer (score 2):

[Libertinus](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus) is a fork of Linux Libertine with bug fixes and very good math support (check out [this example document](https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus/raw/master/documentation/libertinus-testmath.pdf)). It would enable you to use Linux Libertine for math without using `newtxmath`. This is the question title ... (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)).

To be compiled with `xelatex` and Libertinus fonts installed.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[
    math-style=ISO,
    bold-style=ISO,
    partial=upright,
    nabla=upright
]{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}


\begin{document}
The formula \(E=mc^2\) is arguably the most famous formula in physics.

In mathematics, it could be \(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\uppi}-1=0\).

\(\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\uppi^2}{6}\), and
\(\displaystyle \int\displaylimits_{-\infty}^\infty 
   \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) = \sqrt{2\uppi}\).

\(\alpha\beta\gamma\delta\epsilon\zeta\eta\theta\iota\kappa\lambda\mu\nu\xi\pi\rho\sigma\tau\upupsilon\phi\chi\psi\omega \varepsilon\vartheta\varrho\varsigma\varphi\varkappa\)

\(\upalpha\upbeta\upgamma\updelta\upepsilon\upzeta\upeta\uptheta\upiota\upkappa\uplambda\upmu\upnu\upxi\uppi\uprho\upsigma\uptau\upupsilon\upphi\upchi\uppsi\upomega \upvarepsilon\upvartheta\upvarrho\upvarsigma\upvarphi\upvarkappa\)

\(\Alpha\Beta\Gamma\Delta\Epsilon\Zeta\Eta\Theta\Iota\Kappa\Lambda\Mu\Nu\Xi\Pi\Rho\Sigma\Tau\Upsilon\Phi\Chi\Psi\Omega\)

\(\upAlpha\upBeta\upGamma\upDelta\upEpsilon\upZeta\upEta\upTheta\upIota\upKappa\upLambda\upMu\upNu\upXi\upPi\upRho\upSigma\upTau\upUpsilon\upPhi\upChi\upPsi\upOmega\)
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Be aware though: `xe(la)tex` currently (TeX Live 2016) has a bug, which is visible in my screenshot: [Why is the fraction off the math axis in XeTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281549/why-is-the-fraction-off-the-math-axis-in-xetex) . `lualatex` of TeX Live 2016 has a bug as well: [spacing in LuaLaTeX with unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352434/spacing-in-lualatex-with-unicode-math)